# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL (AimTux)

Tags: c++, linux

```
make
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/atgui.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/triggerbottab.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/misctab.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/visualstab.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/skinstab.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/hvhtab.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/modelstab.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Tabs/aimbottab.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Windows/configs.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Windows/main.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Windows/playerlist.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Windows/skinmodelchanger.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/Windows/colors.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ATGUI/atguielements.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/util_sdk.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/patternfinder.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/math.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/draw.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/util.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/entity.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/skins.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/netvarmanager.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Utils/util_items.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/hooker.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/AimTux.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/interfaces.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/config.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/fonts.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/shortcuts.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/json/jsoncpp.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ImGUI/imgui_demo.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ImGUI/imgui.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ImGUI/imgui_impl_sdl.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/ImGUI/imgui_draw.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/modsupport.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/glhook.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/autoblock.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/clantagchanger.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/chams.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/dlights.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/namechanger.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/snipercrosshair.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/autodefuse.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/skinchanger.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/antiaim.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/showranks.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/esp.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/predictionsystem.cpp.o
[ 49%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/asuswalls.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/hitmarkers.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/autoaccept.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/jumpthrow.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/view.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/fakelag.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/resolver.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/teleport.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/showspectators.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/namestealer.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/spammer.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/autostrafe.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/customglow.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/autowall.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/disablepostprocessing.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/airstuck.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/grenadehelper.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/radar.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/recoilcrosshair.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/edgejump.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/fovchanger.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/bhop.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/nosmoke.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/aimbot.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/nosky.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/triggerbot.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/noflash.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/thirdperson.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hacks/valvedscheck.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/PaintTraverse.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/BeginFrame.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/SetMouseCodeState.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/CreateMove.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/EmitSound.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/OverrideView.cpp.o
[ 84%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/DrawModelExecute.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/RenderSmokePostViewmodel.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/Paint.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/FrameStageNotify.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/RenderView.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/FireEventClientSide.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/SetKeyCodeState.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/IN_KeyEvent.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/GetViewModelFOV.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/PlaySound.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/PumpWindowsMessageLoop.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/OnScreenSizeChanged.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/Hooks/FireEvent.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/offsets.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/src/settings.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libAimTux.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/build.make:2616: recipe for target 'libAimTux.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libAimTux.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/AimTux.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this? I'm on the latest ubuntu. I did cmake . and then I ran make -j 4 but after that you can see at the bottom, it says some error and it doesn't work. I have tried the other solutions in the other questions but none of them are working for me. This is one of the first times I've used linux so please treat me almost as a complete noob with linux.

Comment: We frown upon cheat/hack attempts here. Why can't you play the game honourably and honestly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GL package is different depending on your graphics card. Install the correct version:

```
fglrx
fglrx-updates
nvidia-173
nvidia-304-updates
nvidia-304
nvidia-331-updates
```

Install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

Also, make sure you installed the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake g++ gdb git libsdl2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Although now I get a different error. When I put glxinfo | grep OpenGL into the Terminal, I get Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) and when I open up CsGo, I get "Failed to creat GL context: Could not create GL Context: BadValue (Integer parameter out of range for operation)" And I don't know how to accept an answer.

Comment: Seems like a bug in CS:GO https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/1050

Comment: You don't know how to accept an answer? So you skipped the SO tour then?

Comment: Accepting an answer is right below the down arrow under the vote